# Cartesian product error on ALS recommendation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to show a list of movie recommendations for an user. The model has been trained but when trying to show the prediction, I'm getting an error.

```
als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="userID", 
itemCol="movieID", ratingCol="rating")
# ratings is a DataFrame of (movieID, rating, userID)
model = als.fit(ratings)
# allMovies is a DataFrame of (movieID, userID)
# it has userID=0 and all distinct movieID
recommendations = model.transform(allMovies)
recommendations.take(20)
```

Using the `from pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS` library and
when running the last line, I'm getting the error
`Detected cartesian product for LEFT OUTER join between logical plans`.

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For answering my own question. It seems that you shouldn't use `transform` but the `recommendForUserSubset` method.

Answer (score 0):

Before model.transform you have to define ALS something like ALS(input_col = 'something like input feature',output_col = predicted_rating) or you can have this way to work possibly.

```
 rank = 10
 numIterations = 100
 model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations) #where ratings is dataframe
 recommendation = model.predictAll(alMovies).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it to work with this code. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: seems like you got your solution ,just for curiosity what was error  you got while using above code ?

Comment: Sure, I got an `AttributeError: 'ALS' object has no attribute 'train'`